# Want to modify a Plugin - Tweetily - Can I make it tweet a Custom Field instead of Post Title?

Tags: plugins, customization, hacks

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweetily-tweet-wordpress-posts-automatically/

I was wondering if somehow it's possible to make it tweet a Custom Field instead of Post Title?

in top-core.php, at line 214

```
if ($tweet_type == "title" || $tweet_type == "titlenbody") {
        $title = stripslashes($post->post_title);
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        $title = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $title);
    } else {
        $title = "";
    }
```

Can I replace post_title with something else which can do the trick?

Comment: Note that you will lose all modifications if you update the plugin afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do this with :

```
$title = stripslashes( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true) );
```

You just have to replace 'key' with the appropriate key.

See [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)